# How i can i reduce the borderwidth of a chartjs dougnut chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, donut-chart, react-chartjs

This is what i'm trying to achieve from the mockup:

[image: doughnut chart image]

But this is what I've achieved so far using chartjs:

[image: doughnut chart image]

this is my code

```
 datasets: [
            {
              data: [3, 8, 13, 9, 2],
              backgroundColor: [
                "#D51F1F",
                "#9B51E0",
                "#F2994A",
                "#4BD37B",
                "#4285F4"
              ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth:1,
            borderDash:[],
            borderStyle:'dash',
            line: { borderWidth:1 }
        }]
    }

    const options= {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        percentageInnerCutout : 0,
     }
```

I'm setting **borderWidth** as **1**, and it seems not to make the border thinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `cutoutPercentage: 80` in your options. You can increase this to make the white area in the middle of your donut chart larger, or decrease it to make it smaller. You'll need to fiddle with it to get your chart as close to the example as you can.

[Here are the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#config-options)

Answer (score 0):

Doughnut cutoutPercentage was renamed to cutoutand accepts pixels as number and percent as string ending with %.